# Form submission handler creates duplicate Google Calendar events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I modified code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145526/5341700) to suit my needs. I use Google Forms that fill into Google Sheets, and then the script inserts an event into Google Calendar. I have installed a "form submit" trigger to execute the script. The issue I have is that my code starts with the data in the first row of the sheet, adding the same events every time a new form response is added.

Here is my version:

```
//push new events to calendar
function pushToCalendar() {
  //spreadsheet variables
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,16);
  var values = range.getValues(); 

  //calendar variables
  var defaultCalendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()

  var numValues = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     
    //check to see if Start DateTime and End DateTime are filled out
    if ((values[i][3]) && (values[i][4])) {
      //check if it's been entered before  
      if (values[i][6] != 'y') {
        //create event https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp#createEvent
        var newEventTitle = values[i][1] + ' - ' + values[i][2];
        var startDay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][3]), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        var endDay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][4]), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        var newEvent = defaultCalendar.createEvent(newEventTitle, new Date(startDay), new Date(endDay), {location: values[i][2]});
        //get ID
        var newEventId = newEvent.getId();

        //mark as entered, enter ID
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue('y');
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 7).setValue(newEventId);
      }  
    }

    numValues++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by myself: on row 20 i changed the code

```
if (values[i][6] != 'y') {
```

to

```
if (!values[i][6]) {
```

No need to write that `'y'` sign. I also changed

```
sheet.getRange(i+2,6).setValue('y');
```

to
    sheet.getRange(i+2,6).setValue('');

And no duplicates anymore. The code works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the original code is that you are reading the wrong column - JavaScript arrays are 0-base, while the spreadsheet columns are 1-base. Column 6 (from `getRange(i + 2, 6)` is in the array index `5`, i.e. `values[i][5]`, not `values[i][6]`. So you were comparing the `newEventId` with the string `'y'`, which was never going to be the same.

As your solution indicates, removing the condition that `values[i][6]` (aka column 7, where your script writes the created event's ID) is not equal to `'y'` (a condition that was always true), and instead testing for any value will appropriately guard the event creation code. Given the presence of the event ID column, the column in which `'y'` was written is entirely unnecessary.

If you remove that column from your form response sheet, the code guard would then be:

```
//check to see if Start DateTime and End DateTime are filled out
if ((values[i][3]) && (values[i][4])) {
  //check if it's been entered before, by looking in Column F:
  var existingEventId = values[i][5]; // Will be "" (falsy) if not yet added
  if (!existingEventId) {
    ... 
    // Log the event's ID so we don't make a duplicate:
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(newEventId);
  ...
```